# Find best convex approximation of an "almost convex" function

Tags: list-manipulation, mesh, computational-geometry

I've got values of a function of two variables at integer points inside a rectangle, that is, a rectangular table $f(i,j)$, $1\leqslant i\leqslant m$, $1\leqslant j\leqslant n$. The function is very nearly convex, there are just a few points $(i,j)$ (less than 1%) where convexity fails just slightly. There is (afaik) more or less unique way to change these values (or maybe very few neighboring ones too) to obtain a convex function $\tilde f\leqslant f$ which would agree with $f$ almost everywhere.

The only way to do it that I found is to invoke `ConvexHullMesh` on the array of 3D points $(i,j,f(i,j))$ (that is, on the graph of $f$) and then extract relevant part from its `FullForm`. Is there a less hacky way to do what I want?

Comment: Pending answers, your approach seems not hacky, but very much clever.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Thanks for encouragement! Still I would prefer a more "scientific" way... Besides, extracting the needed points may be tricky (still sorting this out)

Comment: In that case you ought to strongly elaborate on the desired properties of $\tilde{f}$ because failing that, you'll be reimplementing the workings of `ConvexHullMesh`. Admittedly, given that you have a rectangular grid of values, a reimplementation might be better in performance.

Comment: it doesnt seem your approach satisfies your `<=` constraint.

Comment: It seems, I've completely overlooked what @george2079 remarked on. That changes a lot.

Comment: @george2079 Might well be... I am confident in my specific case it must be OK but currently cannot really pin down what is crucial for that.

Comment: @george2079 However it would be very helpful and instructive for me if you could provide an example

Comment: @LLlAMnYP As for the desired properties of $\tilde f$ - unfortunately they are not really rigorously formulable. $\tilde f$ must be as close as $f$ at these points as possible, and preferably coincide with it where convexity holds. It might be $\sup$ of convex functions $\leqslant f$ at these points, or minimizing absolute value of difference with $f$ at these points (among convex functions; this would even violate the $\leqslant$ constraint!). I thought this is not so important for the solution of the specific question...

Comment: `Table[{i, j, 
    Sqrt[50- i^2 - j^2] - 2
     KroneckerDelta[i, 0] KroneckerDelta[j, 0]}, {i, -4, 4}, {j, -4, 
    4}] // Flatten[#, 1] & // ConvexHullMesh`. The point at `{0,0}` has a height of `5.07`, but `ConvexHullMesh` leaves it out, so the boundary of the mesh at `{0,0}` has the height of the neighboring points, which is `7`.

Comment: It would appear, that you're going for an $\tilde{f}$ that will contain all the points that are excluded by `ConvexHullMesh`, which would discard some of the neighboring to them points, but I'm not sure, what the appropriate algorithm may be to discard them with minimal losses.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Wow thanks for the cute example! But is not making it 7 the smallest price to obtain (values at these points of) a convex function?

Comment: In fact I now realize there might be some confusion. Your example is what I would call concave rather than convex, and for such functions I would require $\tilde f\geqslant f$ rather  than $\tilde f\leqslant f$.

Comment: Does this question have a 2D equivalent? It might help you formulate your criterea and solution if you could come up with a simple 2d example.